# Rails: 500 error page showing up instead of back trace or debug page in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The problem: Every time I start the rails server in development and navigate to a page that has an error, I get the 500 error page instead of the back trace page that details the specific error and the line it can be found.

For example:
I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/articles/new`, and get this:

> 500 Internal server error
>   Web server cannot perform this request. Please try again later.

Things I have done to avoid this:

(1) commented out in environments/production.rb

```
#consider_all_requests_local = false

#config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

(2) Ensured in environments/development.rb

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

Log files:

> Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-19 21:40:19 -0700
>   Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
>    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IiAVgs285sNZMcs32nnE4WQNFCiZJIfEB8kN/6J7WAc=", "article"=>{"title"=>"dog", "text"=>"home"}, "commit"=>"Save Article"}
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms
>
> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template articles/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
>     * "C:/Users/harry/rails_projects/blog/app/views"
>   ):
>    app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:7:in `create'
>
> Rendered 
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.0ms)

Comment: Set consider all request local to true in your environment file. Also make sure you restarted your server with proper environment.

Comment: In rare cases, this can happen even if `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` is set if the error-handling routine itself encounters an error.

Comment: @Rubyrider that was already set to true by default when i started the rails project.

Comment: @WallyAltman what do you suggest? This is what is happening currently.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to fix your problem.

Comment: one last question: can you make sure you are running your server on development environment ? and can you try restarting your server?

Comment: @Rubyrider how can I confirm this? As of now I use the standard "rails sever" command to start the server.

Comment: bundle exec rails server -e development

Comment: Have you by any chance used something called "Tunngle"? I googled for the exact error string you shared, because that's not what the rails 500 internal server error message looks like. And Tunngle results came up.

Comment: Apparently Tunngle hooks your LAN up to the WAN Internet, so it could definitely be interfering with your local development environment.